# Unable to get FindNext property of range class

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code, it just takes 3 words from user, looks for words in `b`,`c` and `d` and changes value to `XXXXXXXXXXXXX`.

The problem is that I get

> unable to get findnext property of range class

I need this code to do multiple searches with different words and replace values without closing/resetting excel.
And if it is possible, when it does not fiind value in `b`, should go and execute the next piece of code.

The code looks for words in paragraphs.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim x As String
Dim y As String
Dim z As String

x = InputBox("enter word")
y = InputBox("enter word")
z = InputBox("enter word")





With Worksheets(1).Range("b2:b1000")
    Set b = Cells.Find(x)
    If Not b Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = b.Address
        Do

             b.Value = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
             Set b = .FindNext(b)
        Loop While Not b Is Nothing
    End If
End With


With Worksheets(1).Range("c2:c1000")
    Set c = Cells.Find(y)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            c.Value = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing
    End If
End With


With Worksheets(1).Range("d2:d1000")
    Set d = Cells.Find(z)
    If Not d Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = d.Address
        Do
            d.Value = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            Set d = .FindNext(d)
        Loop While Not d Is Nothing
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells.Find(x)` In Excel has an uncanny habit of remembering the last settings. Use full settings as shown [HERE](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) For example `.Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tested this code and if I have a cell with : "Nombre del producto: wok antiadherente verde // Material: Metal // tamaÃ±o: vista general del dibujo // Capacidad: 2500 / 4200ml " and I am looking for the word "verde", it only replaces the word and the rest of the text is still there. – Andrew Cm 9 mins ago

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim firstWord As String
    Dim secondWord As String
    Dim thirdWord As String

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    firstWord = InputBox("enter word")
    secondWord = InputBox("enter word")
    thirdWord = InputBox("enter word")

    With ws
        If firstWord <> "" Then ReplaceText ws.Range("B2:B1000"), firstWord
        If secondWord <> "" Then ReplaceText ws.Range("C2:C1000"), secondWord
        If thirdWord <> "" Then ReplaceText ws.Range("D2:D1000"), thirdWord
    End With

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub

'~~> Identify the cell where the value is found and
'~~> Store it in a range. at the end, directly
'~~> replace all values
Private Sub ReplaceText(rng As Range, txt As String)
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim rngFound As Range

    Set aCell = rng.Find(What:=txt, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell
        Set rngFound = aCell

        Do
            Set aCell = rng.FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                Set rngFound = Union(rngFound, aCell)
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If

    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        rngFound.Value = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks, your code is great.  Can I configure Replace 'What:=firstWord, _'  so it will replace entire text from cell, with XXXXXX ?

Comment: Tested this code and if I have a cell with : "Nombre del producto: wok antiadherente verde // Material: Metal // tamaÃ±o: vista general del dibujo // Capacidad: 2500 / 4200ml "  and I am looking for the word  **"verde"**, it only replaces the word and the rest of the text is still there.

Comment: Ah ok. so you want to replace the entire cell value?

Comment: See the edit that I posted. You may have to refresh the page to see it

Comment: This works great.  Thank you.  I will look through the code and try to understand it, as I am trying to learn VBA .

Answer (score -1):

Your case would be easier to solve if VBA/VB6 supported `Try/Catch`. However, it does not. So we revert to the closest thing possible: `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error Goto 0`.

`On Error Resume Next` will allow errors to happen, and will populate the global object `Err` with the number of the error in VB library. Just set it to 0 before testing for new errors because `On Error Resume Next` does not clear its value.

```
...

Do
  Err = 0   'reset it /ignore any old value
  b.Value = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  On Error Resume Next
  Set b = .FindNext(b)
  On Error Goto 0
Loop While Not b Is Nothing And Err = 0   ' stay in the loop if there are no errors 
...
```

Comment: Bad advice Ahmad. Also this is not the reason why OPs code is not working